# How can we slice ArrayBuffer without copying?

Tags: javascript

I want to fetch some binary encoded data and split it into two objects. It's half Uint32Array and half BigInt64Array. How would I do the split without copying? The [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/slice) say it does the copy.

Comment: Not sure why you don't want a copy, but have you looked at SharedArrayBuffer?

Comment: It seems, Response.blob() is what I was really looking for. I don't want to have 100 mb object and then 2 half-copies of it, so the whole thing would consume 200 mb in total.

Comment: could you add your fetch binary encoded data? at least add an slice of it